# Range of numbers using less than and greater than

Tags: range

I am looking for some clarity on a question I was recently asked in an interview.
Basically I was asked to read a line of code and explain how it should be tested.
Unfortunately I can't remember the line of code exactly but it went something like this.

Input <=3 ; <20 : Output = 10

It was explained as a range.

I read this as a value less than or equal to 3 and less than 20 gives an output of 10. It was then explained that it was greater than or equal to 3 and less than 20. The latter makes more sense but to me it reads less than or equal to 3.

Could someone explain a little more maybe?
I know the code is not correct but I couldn't quite remember the layout when in the middle of the interview!

Thanks.

Comment: It is really hard to help when you can't remember the exact line. Also, knowing the context might help. Is this a pseudocode, a mathemathical expression or a line of code specific to a programming language?

Comment: Sorry I'm afraid none of that was explained. It looked to be to a line of code but not sure of the language. I suppose my question is, can a line of code which is shown roughly as 3<= ; <20 ever read as greater than or equal to 3?

Comment: Please note that, in your question, the unknown is on the left-hand side of the operator whereas on your comment it is on the right-hand side. It makes a big difference. So, if it is shown like `3<= ; 20` although the notation is weird, I would assume that they were defining this interval `[3, 20)`. So the unknown is greater than or equal to 3 and smaller than 20.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and apologies for the confusion. That's exactly the detail I was confused about. So just to be clear, if the code is written like <=3: this means less than or equal to three? If the code is written like 3<=: this means greater than or equal to?

Comment: No worries. Yes, I would assume exactly that since on one side of the `<=` operator there is 3, the other side should be the unknown, in your case the input. In summary, `input <= 3` vs. `3 <= input`